# Using libtins to recreate IP packet change its header

Tags: c++, c++11, networking, ip, libtins

I have a `uint8_t*` buffer which I get by doing `buf.data()`. It's a buffer of an IP packet.

I want to change the source address and recalculate the checksum, so I recreated the packet in libtins by doing what you see below:

```
//prints original packet  
for (size_t i = 0; i < buf.size(); i++)
{
    printf("%x ", buf.data()[i]);
}
printf("\n");

Tins::IP pa = Tins::IP(buf.data(), buf.size());
pa.src_addr(newIpv4address);
uint8_t *packetData = pa.serialize().data();

//prints libtins packet created from original packet
for (size_t i = 0; i < buf.size(); i++)
{
    printf("%x ", packetData[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

The problem is that the packet printed from libtins appears with a different header:

```
45 0 0 34 0 0 40 0 40 6 6b 53 c0 a8 45 1 ac d9 1c ee 0 20 0 50 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 80 2 fd e8 a5 4d 0 0 2 4 5 b4 3 3 0 4 2 0 0 0 

60 b 0 34 62 76 0 0 d0 8 0 28 62 76 0 0 ac d9 1c ee 0 20 0 50 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 80 2 fd e8 eb 47 0 0 2 4 5 b4 3 3 0 4 2 0 0 0
```

I then tried to change the `buf` with the new packet even though it looks different:

```
uint8_t* b = buf.data();
uint8_t* o = pa.serialize().data();

for (int i = 0; i < buf.size(); i++)
{
    b[i] = o[i];
}

auto p = Tins::IP(buf.data(), buf.size());
```

but on the line `auto p = Tins::IP(buf.data(), buf.size());` I get:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Tins::malformed_packet'
  what():  Malformed packet
```

which is strange since it's literally a packet generated from libtins.

What am I doing wrong? According to [libtins documentation](http://auto%20p%20=%20Tins::IP(buf.data(),%20buf.size());) I can create a libtins packet from a buffer and a size.

**UPDATE:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <tins/ip.h>

int main()
{
    const int packet_size = 52;
    uint8_t ip_packet[] = {
        69, 0, 0, 52, 0, 0, 64, 0, 64, 6, 107,
        83, 192, 168, 69, 1, 172, 217, 28, 238,
        0, 112, 0, 80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 128,
        2, 253, 232, 164, 253, 0, 0, 2, 4, 5, 180,
        3, 3, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0};

    std::cout << "packet BEFORE " << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < packet_size; i++)
    {
        printf("%x ", ip_packet[i]);
    }

    uint8_t b[52];
    for (int i = 0; i < packet_size; i++)
    {
        b[i] = ip_packet[i];
    }
    printf("\n");

    Tins::IP pa = Tins::IP(b, packet_size);
    pa.src_addr("172.78.123.76");
    uint8_t *packetData = pa.serialize().data();
    std::cout << "TINS packet: " << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < packet_size; i++)
    {
        printf("%x ", packetData[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
packet BEFORE 
45 0 0 34 0 0 40 0 40 6 6b 53 c0 a8 45 1 ac d9 1c ee 0 70 0 50 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 80 2 fd e8 a4 fd 0 0 2 4 5 b4 3 3 0 4 2 0 0 0 
TINS packet: 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 90 68 1 0 0 0 0 ac d9 1c ee 0 70 0 50 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 80 2 fd e8 83 c 0 0 2 4 5 b4 3 3 0 4 2 0 0 0
```

Comment: What is your `newIpv4address` like?

Comment: @NutCracker a simple string "172.78.123.76"

Comment: I tried the same thing you did here, but with `expected_packet` variable in the _ip_test.cpp_ and everything is working as it should

Comment: @NutCracker sorry what the name `expected_packet` has to do with it?

Comment: Same as you used `buf` packet, I have reused the bytes from `expected_packet` variable located in _ip_test.cpp_. Can you show me your `buf` content?

Comment: @NutCracker take a look at my new update. I simulated the buf. As you see I get a strange header for the tins packet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the sample IP packet you have provided, I've done the following:

```cpp
uint8_t ip_packet[] = {
    69,  0,   0,   52,  0,   0,   64, 0, 
    64,  6,   107, 83,  192, 168, 69, 1,
    172, 217, 28,  238, 0,   112, 0,  80,
    0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  0,
    128, 2,   253, 232, 164, 253, 0,  0,
    2,   4,   5,   180, 3,   3,   0,  4,
    2,   0,   0,   0
};

Tins::IP ip(ip_packet, sizeof(ip_packet));
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(ip_packet); i++)
    std::cout << +ip_packet[i] << " ";

std::cout << std::endl;

ip.src_addr("192.155.32.10");

auto data = ip.serialize();
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    std::cout << +data[i] << " ";

std::cout << std::endl;
```

and I get the following output:

```
69 0 0 52 0 0 64 0 64 6 107 83 192 168 69 1 172 217 28 238 0 112 0 80 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 128 2 253 232 164 253 0 0 2 4 5 180 3 3 0 4 2 0 0 0
69 0 0 52 0 0 64 0 64 6 144 87 192 155 32 10 172 217 28 238 0 112 0 80 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 128 2 253 232 202 1 0 0 2 4 5 180 3 3 0 4 2 0 0 0
```

so it works as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much! Turns out the thing I was doing different from yours was `uint8_t *packetData = pa.serialize().data();` which quickly gets destructed so we get undefined behaviour

Comment: @LucasZanella glad I could help